# half bridge secondary temp

Tags: power-supply

I used this schematic for making a power supply. Output is single instead of double and is 36 V, 20 A.

- Core is ETD44.
- Freq is 50 kHz.
- Primary is 30 turn Litz wire (6 × 0.55). - - - Secondary is 8 turn Litz wire (21 × 0.55) so current density is 4 A/mm<sup>2</sup>.

There is a problem in transformer secondary winding. After 30 seconds at full load secondary winding becomes very very hot and I can't use power supply more than 1 minute. What is cause of this extreme heat in secondary?

[image]

Comment: What are the no load losses? Core loss? copper loss?

Comment: hi problem is at full load with 20amps output.why you ask about no load losses?

Comment: The loss budget helps identify where the problem lies. ferrite losses? copper losses?  ESR? ESL?  idle losses?

Comment: The core size is ETD44 but what is the core material you have used and what is specified in the design? Where does the design come from?

Comment: The schematic uses a [core size of ETD59](https://ebiz.fair-rite.com/newfair/mobile/pdfs/mFair-Rite%20Catalog%2017th%20Edition%20ETD%20Cores.pdf) - a bigger core. Perhaps the smaller size is contributing to extra heating: \$A_e(\text{cm}^2)\$.